# Flatten column values into a string

Tags: sql-server

Although I've been using Sql Server on an occasional basis for yonks, I didn't realise until I stumbled across it the other day that you could do something like this:

```
declare @result varchar(8000)

select @result = ''

select @result = @result + acolumn+ ' '

from atable
```

Nothing I'd read in the Transact-Sql docs led me to think of using a construct like that rather than e.g. a cursor.  My question: Is this construct supported by other versions of Sql or is it Sql Server-specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Sql server specific. The statements you mentioned are T-SQL statements and they are only available for Sql Server.

Answer (score 3):

Do not do this, because it [depends on the physical implementation and internal access paths](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us). Please read the article on [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#_Toc205129494) for several correct approaches such as the `FOR XML PATH('')` approach.